# How do you parse context-sensitive C-code?

Tags: c, parsing, lexical-analysis

One issue I ran into was that C must be context-sensitive and cannot be parsed with one token of lookahead.  For example

```
int main1;
int main() {}
```

That's the simplest example I can think of in which both a function definition and a variable declaration start with the same token type.  You'd have to look all the way ahead to the left paren or semicolon to determine what to parse.

My question is, how is this accomplished?  Does the lexical analyzer have some tricks up its sleeve to do the lookahead and emit an invisible token distinguishing the two?  Do modern parses have many tokens of lookahead?

Comment: "Context sensitive" has nothing to do with how much lookahead you need.  "Context sensitive" means that you have to examine other parts of the input to figure out what your code means.  So "`x * y;`" could mean "multiply `x` by `y`" or it could mean "declare variable `y` with type `x*`" -- you cannot figure that out without knowing whether `x` is a value or a type -- this is the "context" in "context-sensitive".  Lookahead is something else.

Comment: Fair enough.  I suppose I used the term context-sensitive incorrectly.  I know that GCC uses a recursive descent parser and I'm just wondering how they deal with this ambiguity.

Comment: If you are interested in compilers, the field has a very rich set of underlying theories and I recommend getting a book.  "Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools" by Aho, Sethi, and Ullman is a good choice, even if you never work on a compiler.

Answer (score 8):

You should read up on LR or shift-reduce parsers. They assemble the parse tree bottom-up. In the case of the `main` function it goes like:

- shift `int` into the stack as a TYPE terminal token
- shift `main` into the stack as an IDENTIFIER terminal token
- shift `(` into the stack
- shift `)` into the stack
- remove the `(` and `)` and replace with an ARGLIST non-terminal token
- shift `{` into the stack
- shift `}` into the stack
- remove those and replace with a STMT_BLOCK non-terminal token
- remove the TYPE, IDENTIFIER, ARGLIST, and STMT_BLOCK tokens, and replace with a FUNCTION_DEF token.

Of course, every time it does a replacement, it builds a new fragment of parse tree and attaches it to the new token.
(I made up those token names.)

It works under control of a finite state machine that recognizes the pattern of tokens on the stack and, together with the next (single) token of input, decides whether to shift the next token in, or apply one of the grammar rules to reduce a group of tokens on the stack into a single one. The FSM is built by the parser generator from a list of the grammar rules.

It is called LR because it reads input tokens from the left, but applies grammar rules from the right. It is distinct from LL, or recursive-descent, which applies grammar rules from the left. Pascal is an LL(1) language. C is not LL(1), so requires an LR(1) parser.
It allows C, for example, to embed almost anything in nested parentheses without confusing the parser.

I hope that helps you see what is going on.

Comment: You have an interesting point.  However, I've heard that GCC switched over to a recursive descent parser at some point.  Clearly they MUST run into this problem, right?

Comment: @Scott: That's what [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection#Front-ends) says. If so, I would think it's pretty tricky, as in parsing `(((*((int *f())[])((some_expression)))))` or some such. When you dive into the parens you don't know if you're parsing a type, or an array of type, or an expression (and whether it's l-value or r-value), so you have to somehow postpone that decision.

Comment: There are a number of errors in this post.  1: C is not in LR(1).  LR(1) is strictly context insensitive, and C is context sensitive.  However, you can hack together a C parser by adding a symbol table to a simpler (LALR or LL) parser, postponing certain decisions, and hand-writing your tokenizer.  2: Almost nobody uses LR(1) parsers, it is much more common to see LALR(1).  LR(1) parsers are harder to generate.  Continued...

Comment: Continued: 3: LL is not the same thing as recursive descent.  LL is a class of languages, recursive descent is one possible way to parse LL languages.  4: The machine used by a shift-reduce parser is called a "pushdown automaton", which is not an FSM.  A finite state machine can only parse regular languages, and a pushdown automaton has a potentially unbounded amount of state.  5: Just because it's not LL(1) doesn't mean LR(1) is good enough.  Some languages are LL(2) or LL(k) or even more complicated.

Comment: @Dietrich: Just checking the dragon book, it looks like it's not completely incorrect to call it a FSM, because a PDA is an FSM that can read it's stack as well as the input. Anyway, thanks for your clarifications. (For me, it's been a while.)